# Pandas show dataframe columns with boolean selection

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say i have this dataframe:

```
df:
        W           X           Y           Z
A   2.706850    0.628133    0.907969    0.503826
B   0.651118    -0.319318   -0.848077   0.605965
C   -2.018168   0.740122    0.528813    -0.589001
D   0.188695    -0.758872   -0.933237   0.955057
E   0.190794    1.978757    2.605967    0.683509
```

i can retrieve a column without the rows with negative values like this:

```
df[df['W'] > 0]

        W           X           Y           Z
A   2.706850    0.628133    0.907969    0.503826
B   0.651118    -0.319318   -0.848077   0.605965
D   0.188695    -0.758872   -0.933237   0.955057
E   0.190794    1.978757    2.605967    0.683509
```

I want to do opposite of this and remove columns with negative values (for curiosity)

I know that we retrieve rows with .loc[] function and i have tried `df.loc['A' > 0]` which gives me this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-6331436fa402> in <module>
----> 1 df.loc['A' > 0]

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

And `df.loc[df['A']>0]` gives me a KeyError because `df['A']>0` returns a list

Let's assume this dataframe is a database and i want to retrieve columns for which the values of row 'A' is positive, is there another function to retrieve like that or its not something people would do ideally?

Comment: `df.loc['A'][df.loc['A'] > 0]` shouldn't raise `KeyError`

Comment: @Mstaino Dude this was exactly what i was looking for, Thanks my dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can certainly do it with loc, but need a little twist:

```
import pandas as pd
a = {'a':[4,5,6,3,-3,1,-3],'b':[3,5,-2,5,-6,3,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df = df.T
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6
a  4  5  6  3 -3  1 -3
b  3  5 -2  5 -6  3  5
```

And then filtering with:

```
print(df.loc[['a'],df.ge(0).all()]) #Only those who are greater or equal than 0, in all cases
```

Returns this where you get selected only the columns that have all positive values for the selected row. Of course you can change this to filter for only another specific row, or a group of rows:

```
   0  1  3  5
a  4  5  3  1
```

Comment: i tried this and it gives me following error:
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

Comment: Edited, missed a value.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to flip the inequality from greater than (>) to less than (<).

```
df[df['W'] < 0]
```